# Centre of matrix ring isomorphic to centre of ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Show that the centre of $\mathfrak{M}_n(R)$ is isomorphic to the centre of $R$.

Book's solution:

> If $A=(a_{ij})$ is in the centre of $R$, then $Ae_{rs}=e_{rs}A$, hence $S_ia_{ir}e_{is}=S_ja_{rj}e_{sj}$. The only term on both sides is $a_{rr}e_{rs}=a_{ss}e_{rs}$, hence $A=aI$, where $a$ is in the centre of $R$.

I get that you can swap the $e_{ij}$s and the $a_{ij}$s (as the $a_{ij}$s are in the center). But once you set $i=r$ and $j=s$, don't you get $S_ra_{rr}e_{rs}=S_se_{ss}a_{rs}$? How can you cancel out $S_r$ and $S_s$ (which I suppose are matrices in $\mathfrak{M}_n(R)$)? And even when you do, how do you deduce that $A=aI$?

Comment: Ok, I tried that and posted my attempt as an answer. Do you think you could have a look and let me know if it's ok? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a matrix commutes with all other matrices, then it must be a multiple of the identity. But which multiples are ok? For any matrix of the form $rI$ ($r$ is an element of $R$), we must have
$$rIaI=aIrI$$
Taking out the $I$s (by definition of identity) we are left with
$ra=ar$
which only holds if $a$ is in the centre of $R$.

(EDITED as per  @user26857's comment)

Comment: If you can show that a matrix which commute with all matrices has the form $aI$, then this commutes in particular with all matrices of the form $rI$ ($r\in R$), so $ar=ra$ for all $r\in R$.